# Execute something from path in a specific directory in linux

Tags: linux

I was wondering if it was possible to execute something from path in a specific directory, e.g. I have a program called STAR in my path on linux, and I have a sh script written to execute it multiple times, however when it runs it generates the output (which is composed on multiple files) in the current working directory. Now there isn't any built in functionality in the program itself for redirecting the output.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why doesn't your script simply `cd` to the appropriate place before running `STAR`? Am I missing something?

Comment: That popped into my literally 2 seconds after posting this. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cwd is changed using the underlying `chdir()` system call, which is called by `cd` in your shell. If the script dumps to the cwd and you want it to dump somewhere else, just use `cd` in your wrapper script to change to the directory where you want the output.